# ¿Cómo deben ir definidas las rutas absolutas en AJAX y otras direcciones, al subir sitio dinámico a un hosting?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Estoy tratando se subir un sitio dinámico: PHP MySQL y con algunas cosas en AJAX a un hosting gratuito de prueba. Pero al ingresar a las páginas que envían datos por AJAX y reciben información de la base de datos, no carga los datos.

No sé si sea algo de las rutas absolutas, ya le cambié el directorio raíz por la carpeta generada del hosting. Además de que otras páginas dinámicas que reciben información de consultas, no imprimen ninguna. Y algunas funciones que ocupo para mandar a traer esos datos como `fetch_all` dice que están indefinidas, siendo que de manera a servidor local trabaja todo bien.

Tengo problemas con el contenido en AJAX, e información solicitada que no se imprime.

El primer archivo es el de conexión a la base de datos. con el nombre y usuario del hosting.
El otro archivo  es de la ruta absoluta con la URL del servidor local que tenía y la del directorio por defecto del hosting.

```html
<?php
/**
 * 
 *
 * @return resource Recurso asociado a la conexión MySQLi
 */
function conectar() {
  $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'u601071608_cebus', 'cebadmin', 'u601071608_vasco');

  if ($conexion->connect_error !== null) {
    die($conexion->connect_error);
  }
  if ($conexion->set_charset('utf8') === false) {
    die($conexion->error);
  }
  return $conexion;
}

/**
 * Cierre la conexión MySQLi y devuelve el resultado.
 *
 * @param resource $conexion Recurso de conexión MySQLi
 *
 * @return boolean Estado del cierre de la conexión
 */
function desconectar($conexion) {
  /* Forma correcta de cerrar la conexión */
  return $conexion->close();
}
```

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#registrar').click(function(){
      var buscar = $('#buscar').val();

      if ( $.trim(buscar).length > 0 ){
        $.ajax({
          //url en servidor local era::
          //url: "/cebprocedular/Controller/reg_alum2.php",
          url: "/public_html/Controller/reg_alum2.php",
          //url: "modal_modificar.php",
          method: "POST",
          data:{buscar:buscar},
          cache:false,
          beforeSend:function(){
            $('#registrar').val("Consultando...");
          },
          success:function(data){
            $('#registrar').val("BUSCAR");
            if(data){
              $("#result").html(data);
            };
          }
        });
      };
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Tendrías que especificarlo sin tu carpeta root cual es public_html

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría revisar la información del servidor con [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php), concretamente la información de variables de entorno.

Como ya han mencionado las rutas relativas son la mejor opción:

> In general, it is considered best-practice to use relative URLs, so that your website will not be bound to the base URL of where it is currently deployed. For example, it will be able to work on localhost, as well as on your public domain, without modifications.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, algo simple puede ser declarar una función en ámbito global y llamarla cada vez que uses una URL. Esto te permite modificar todas tus URLs desde un sólo lugar.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function getUrl() {
      return "https://algun_magico_dominio/algun_magico_lugar";
    }

      $(document).ready(function(){
         var url =  getUrl() + "/public_html/Controller/reg_alum2.php";
       console.log(url);
      });
</script>
```

Este acercamiento puede ir creciendo, en lugar de usar una función puedes usar un objeto con muchas propiedades que puedan serte útiles, como variables de entorno, para la comunicación usas un lenguaje de lado del servidor y generas dinámicamente los valores opcionalmente desde una base de datos o un archivo de configuración en XML o JSON,

El siguiente fragmento de código fue tomado de la gmail si revisas la etiqueta head (en gmail) podras encontrar varios script de este tipo

```html
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var GM_START_TIME=(new Date).getTime();var GM_SUPPORTED_IE_VERSION="9.0";var GM_SUPPORTED_GECKO_VERSION="21";var GM_SUPPORTED_CHROME_VERSION="23";var GM_SUPPORTED_SAFARI_VERSION="5.2";var GM_MOOSE_URL="";var GM_NO_COOKIE_URL="";var GM_NO_ACTIVEX_URL="";var GM_APP_NAME="Gmail";var GM_ACTION_TOKEN="";
// ]]></script>
```

Para tus rutas del lado del servidor, tomando en cuenta que hablamos de PHP, puedes manejar algo parecido: creas un archivo de constantes. Algo como:

```php
<?php

define('URL_ROOT','/lugar_magico');

define('URL_IMG', URL_ROOT . '/assets/dir');

define('URL_CTR_DIR', URL_ROOT . '/app/ctr/');

//---------------------------

/*En cada archivo*/

require_once(URL_CTR_DIR.'controlador.php');

var_dump(URL_CTR_DIR.'controlador.php');
```